# Javascript 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'blah' of undefined '

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test if an array element is undefined:

```
  if(typeof selected[i].facet != 'undefined')
  {
       //do stuff
  }
```

gives me

```
Javascript 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'facet' of undefined '
```

Comment: Well are you sure your selected table contains an i element ?

Comment: try this:

    if(selected[i] && typeof selected[i].facet != 'undefined')
    {
       //do stuff
    }

You should also test that selected[i] is defined and then if it has a 'facet' property.

Comment: Make your loop condition so that `i` will never be out of bounds... ?

Comment: thats an iterator set to 0 to start with in a surrounding loop. For argument sake, i could be replaced with 0.

Comment: Why "for argument sake"? If `i` could be replace with `0`, then are you saying that you actually replaced `i` with `0` and received the same error? There's too little context in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test both the array index and the property:

```
if (selected[i] && selected[i].facet !== undefined) { // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if((selected[i]) && (selected[i].facet != undefined))
  {
       //do stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just do your loop properly

```
for (var i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; ++i) {
    //selected[i] will always be a valid index in the array
}
```

Should it be the case that `selected[i]` is a valid index in the array, but `undefined` regardless, then you don't semantically need an array but a dictionary with integers as keys. In that case, you can loop through it with `for( var key in map )`. Aim to fix the source of errors instead of fighting the symptoms.

Comment: This may be the cause of the issue, but maybe not. It could be that the `i` is in range, but the value is set to `undefined`. OP really needs to give more context.

Comment: @CrazyTrain sure. And even in that case still the cause of the disease needs to be fixed (crazy code that uses undefined array indices) and not pepper the code with annoying work arounds. There has been only one use case for array with holes... when you semantically don't actually need an array or when implementing a hash table.